# How to change property value at Runtime

Tags: java, spring

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load property value?
Is there a way to change some of properties at runtime? 
Is there a automatized way in Spring Framework?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the properties in the spring bean definition at run time.But you can  dynamically add properties during the preparation.You can override PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer like this,

```
public class SpringPropertiesLoader extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

@Override
protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {
    super.loadProperties(props);
    props.put("myProp","myValue");
}
}
```

and then, use this class instead of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in the spring xml.